Как запустить nodemailer на nuxt 3?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно собрать проект на nuxt 3, чтобы при деплое на хостинг работал nodemailer (использовал Vercel для деплоя)? Собрал проект через npm run generate, но при отправки на email через форму выдаёт ошибку, что такого post запроса не найдено

FetchError: [POST] "/api/nodemailer": 404 Not Found

Как исправить эту ошибку?
